# GDebi error at launch (Ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: 21.04, gdebi

I'm getting a strange error message when launching gdebi-gtk from terminal. It prompts an error window which shows as follows:

```
  Downloading the package failed: file «» «g-io-error-quark: Operation not supported (15)»
```

Already tried reinstalling `gdebi` and `gdebi-core` packages with no success. Any ideas on a possible fix?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346516/while-opening-gdebi-g-io-error-quark-ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo#comment2301037_1346516

Comment: "launching gdebi-gtk from terminal" in which folder and which file-system?

Comment: @N0rbert this is just a regular terminal instance running on /home directory, and the issue seems independent from the folder